# Python: Iterate over list items, select other random item, with prob p, swap items

Tags: python

As in the title the problem involves iterating over a list, selecting a random other item, and with a probability p, swap them.
I must be close, but am getting the index out of range error. I can't think of the case where the index would be out of range.

```
    lst = [x for x in range(10)]

    for i in lst:
        random_index = random.randint(1, len(lst))
        if random.random() <= p:
            lst[i], lst[random_index] = lst[random_index], lst[i]
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Where you have `lst[i]`, you are assuming that `i` is an index into `lst`. Did you mean: `for i in range(len(lst)):`?

Comment: If `random_index == len(lst)`, you're out of range.

Comment: `random.randint(m, n)` returns an output `o` in the inclusive range of values from `m <= o <= n`.

Comment: Shouldn't the probability be a list for each item?

Comment: Python lists are 0-based but your code seems to be assuming 1-based.

Comment: Did you mean: `random_index = random.randint(0, len(lst)-1)`?

Comment: Please, make sure the code you're posting is free of typos: missing closing parenthesis after `random.randint(1, len(lst)` and wrong indentation in `if ...`.

Comment: Ok, I see you've updated the code to fix the indentation and brackets. Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Hi @quamrana thanks for your help. New here, do you mean edit to show the correct code for the solution? The error had nothing to do with these syntax errors, they were just slip ups in copying over the code

Comment: Your `IndexError` is the error you are getting. Please update your question with the full error traceback. This includes the line of code that produces that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `random.randint(1, len(lst))` will produce a random integer from 1 to 10, *inclusively*, meaning 10 is included and that will generate `IndexError`. To fix, you need to adjust:

```py
lst = list(range(10))
for index, element in enumerate(lst):
    random_index = random.randint(0, len(lst) - 1)
    if random.random() < p:
        lst[index], lst[random_index] = lst[random_index], element
```

However, unless this is a homework, you are better off using the shuffle function to achieve the same result with less effort:

```py
lst = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(lst)
```